# LIst of dirs without trailing slash "/"

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I'd like a list (one item per line) of a dir. But the last character is a "/"

```
 ls /var/lib/mysql/ | grep -v "\."
```

This shows:

```
 wachuwar_funkfow/
 wachuwar_prueba/
 webdeard_arde/
```

And I'd like

```
 wachuwar_funkfow
 wachuwar_prueba
 webdeard_arde
```

I'd appreciate help

Comment: It looks like your `ls` command is aliased, as it doesn't normally display the trailing slash. Type `alias` on your bash prompt and tell us if there's a line that looks like `alias ls='ls -F ...'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably, your `ls`  is aliased or defined as a function in your `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` or elsewhere.

Try the full path to `ls` like

```
/bin/ls /var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: A lot of thanks. It's better solution because show me another question ls aliases...

Answer (score 6):

Probably you've defined alias for `ls` which is doing that.

To run `ls` directly, run as `\ls`, e.g.

```
\ls /var/lib/mysql/
```

---

To see what's aliased to, run: `type ls`.

If so, remove alias by:

```
unalias ls
```

---

Otherwise, here is the workaround:

```
for dir in `ls -1 .`; do echo $dir; done
```

Answer (score 4):

You should check your aliases for `ls`. For example,

```
$> alias ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

`-F` flag appends directory indicator, so you should remove it from your `ls` aliases if you don't need it.

About *one item by line*. `ls` have usable `-1` flag, so it should works like

```
ls -1 /var/lib/mysql/
wachuwar_funkfow
wachuwar_prueba
webdeard_arde
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ls /var/lib/mysql/ | grep -v "\." | sed 's/\/$//'
```

The last sed commands searches for a line which has an ending / (which is backslashed) and replaces it with empty string.

Comment: Piping grep to sed is redundant; refactor the grep into the sed script. `ls | sed '/\./d;s%/$%%'`

Answer (score 2):

if you have a command that is also an alias, you can bypass the alias and execute the command directly with these methods:

```
ls            # runs the alias
command ls    # runs the command
\ls           # runs the command
```

Answer (score 1):

To exclude files that have a dot in their name, instead of using `grep -v` you can use:

```
shopt -s extglob
\ls -d !(*.*)
```

The backslash bypasses the alias which is likely similar to one of:

```
alias ls=ls -F
alias ls=ls -p
alias ls=ls --classify
alias ls=ls --file-type
alias ls=ls --indicator-style=WORD
```

Where "WORD" is one of `slash`, `file-type` or `classify`.